# Drupal 7 is not sending emails

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-7, sendmail

I've a website created with drupal 7 with a customized theme, all seems to be fine except the contact form is not working.

I have tested the server installation using a very basic PHP script to send emails, and the server seems to be well configured, but still Drupal does not send the emails.

As I'm less than a newbie in drupal, can any one tell me what I need to check to know where the problem is coming from, that I can hopefully fix it ?

Further informations:

- I have confirmed that the contact module is activated
- I check the permissions, and every body is allowed to send emails
- I don't get any error after filling the contact form and sending it.

**UPDATE**

This is the scritp I used to test if my server is configured to send emails:

```
<?php
    $to = "myemail@domaine.com";
    $subject = "Hi!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
            echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    } else {
            echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
    }
```

Comment: try to look for logs of mail software.

Comment: Thanks @GeoPhoenix for the fast reply, any idea where can I find the logs ?

Comment: if you control your server, from a cpanel, or other server interface, you should check there first, otherwise it depends on your operating system, if its a linux server try at `/var/log/mail`

Comment: Don't forget to check Drupals own logs. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As GeoPhonix suggested to me, I had a look on the log files on my server `/var/log/mail.lo` and I noticed that the email was sent but to a different email address which was set there by the website creator, and as I'm a less than newbie I could figure where the email address was set, following are the steps I solved my problem with:

---

1. using the command `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` I could watch the log changes
2. I sent an email using the drupal contant page
3. I noticed the log changed, and the email was successfully sent to a wrong email address.
4. I didn't know where to change the email so I search using `phpmyadmin` the whole database to fin the email in the webform table
5. I search every part in drupal administrative interface where the word `webform` was mentioned to find where to change the email config
6. after some time I find it in: content -> contact page -> webform -> emails and there was the email specified differently from the default contact email.

---

I just wanted to write what I did, may be someone will have the same issue or a similar one, that he can have a idea how to debug things

Comment: Hi Abu! I have installed Drupal 7 in windows. Anyway I can check the logs of drupal in windows? I cannot log into my drupal localhost account because of incorrect password and I tried to send email to my email account it isn't working. So, I wanted to check the logs as you did but I have no idea how to do it in a Windows os.

Comment: Hi @archer, do you have a mail server installed in your machine ? (P.S: if you just want to reset you password, you can do so from the database)

Comment: I tried to reset it from database using this link - https://drupal.org/node/1023428 but looks like I gave 5 attempts with wrong password and it locked me out

Comment: okay, but you can also unlock it from database using PhpMyAdmin, and what about the mail server ? did you install it on your machine ?

Comment: no i have not installed mail server, Abu. I have not tried PhpMyAdmin, is there any link I can look at using PhpMyadmin?

Comment: see [How to unlock the super admin after accidentally blocking](http://www.kingmoney.net/development/blocked-or-deleted-super-admin-drupal-)

Comment: this: https://drupal.org/node/729064 and this: [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=unlock+drupal+account+phpmyadmin&oq=unlock+drupal+account+phpmyadmin&gs_l=hp.3..33i21.48500.67888.1.68158.40.37.3.0.0.3.1902.21906.1j4j12j4j2j0j3j3j6.35.0....0.0..1c.1.20.hp.28fVLZM35Bg&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099%2Cd.bGE%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.c75bKy5EQ0A.O&fp=915928d32c2bfcfd&biw=1280&bih=650)